# Jenkins Group jobs together to define Build periodically on all jobs in the group

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible, maybe using a plugin, to group jobs together on jenkins to define Build periodically on all the jobs in the group?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Eyal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use the [Jenkins Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin).

You create a new parent job (a build flow one) with the following configuration:

```
build( "your.job.A" )
build( "your.job.B" )
build( "your.job.C" )
```

Next, you just have to schedule your parent job in the "build triggers" section:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! looks like a great solution. i will use it.